# javascript listeners increase, does it increase memory usage?

Tags: javascript

I write an webgl app with only es6 there is no other library. And I use listeners for mouse event and setintervals for camera moving and settimeout metod for xhttp call.

I open chrome console and record a performance record. I see Listeners are increase some of them my timers seen on profile record but some timer event only have id like: `Timer ID 2` does it increase memory usage? Or what can I do ?

Comment: Yes, but except in unreasonably huge numbers, only by an insignificant amount

Comment: @CertainPerformance that really depends on what is done in this event listener. OP talks about mouse events and setIntervals (and anecdotally webgl) . If they do start a new Interval of say 20ms at every mousemove, which itself adds the same listener + triggers a repaint of their canvas, then in a few seconds their code will crash any decent browser. To OP, don't add multiple listeners, you don't need it. If you do see multiple event listeners that gets added over time, this means that some of your code gets called many times while a single iteration would be enough. Yes, it may blow your mem'

Comment: @Kalido my timers period about 50 ms, I check my listeners and I can not detect override. Its my mistake or browser can't handle it ? what is unreasonably huge numbers like 1000 or  thousands ?

Comment: In what part of your code do listeners increase? They're hardly necessary, so that is - by definition - a memory leak.

Comment: Wait I have a doubt now, when you say "increase" what do mean exactly? I understood that you get n, then n+1, then n+n' event listeners attached to the same EventTarget. Is that so or do you mean something else? Otherwise, only two same listeners on the same target are already too much.

Comment: @Kaiido I see in performance record on dev tools. Yellow line it means listerers,  are increase